# Remove empty lines followed by a pattern

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find a way to remove empty lines which are found in my asciidoc file before a marker string, such as:

```
//Empty line
[source,shell]
```

I'd need:

```
[source,shell]
```

I'm trying with:

```
sed '/^\s*$\n[source,shell]/d' file
```

however it doesn't produce the expected effect (even escaping the parenthesis). Any help ?

Comment: Is it always before `[source,shell]` or it could be anything?

Comment: No I need to preserve other empty lines. Just delete empty lines before code blocks. Thanks

Comment: yes lines start with "[source" as it's a marker for asciidoc

Comment: I'm afraid not. This removes all empty lines in the document. I want to preserve other empty lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this **awk-script** to delete previous empty line:

```
awk -v desired_val="[source,shell]" 
'BEGIN { first_time=1 }
 { 
   if ( $0 != desired_val && first_time != 1) { print prev };
   prev = $0;
   first_time = 0;
 }
 END { print $0 }' your_file
```

Next script is little more than previous, but provides deleting all empty lines before desired value.

```
# AWK script file
# Provides clearing all empty lines in front of desired value 
# Usage: awk -v DESIRED_VAL="your_value" -f "awk_script_fname" input_fname

BEGIN { i=0 }
{ 
  # If line is empty - save counts of empty strings
  if ( length($0) == 0 ) { i++; }

  # If line is not empty and is DESIRED_VAL, print it  
  if ( length ($0) != 0 && $0 == DESIRED_VAL )
  {
    print $0; i=0;
  }

  # If line is not empty and not DESIRED_VAL, print all empty str and current
  if ( length ($0) != 0 && $0 != DESIRED_VAL )
  {   
    for (m=0;m<i;m++) { print ""; } i=0; print $0;
  }
}

# If last lines is empty, print it
END { for (m=0;m<i;m++) { print ""; } }
```

This is awk-script used by typing followed command:

`awk -v DESIRED_VAL="your_value" -f "awk_script_fname" input_fname`

Answer (score 0):

Your sed line doesn't work because sed processes one line at a time, so it will not match a pattern that includes `\n` unless you manipulate the pattern space.

If you still want to do it with sed:

```
sed '/^$/{N;s/\n\(\[source,shell]\)/\1/}' file
```

How it works: When matching an empty line, read the next line into the pattern space and remove the empty line if a marker is found. *Note that this won't work correctly if you have two empty lines before the marker,* as the first empty line will consume the second one and there will be no matching with the marker.